# Fatal error in Xampp after Update: Cannot use isset()

Tags: php, xampp, isset

When I open old project in Xampp I have trouble with isset code. Actually its happening since I updated my Xampp from `1.7.3 to 3.2.1 xampp`. Looks like the error is in this line:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= CITY_COUNT; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= CITY_COUNT; $j++) {
        if (isset(@$_POST[$i . '_' . $j]))
            //
            $distances[$i][$j] = @$_POST[$i . '_' . $j];
        else if (isset(@$_POST[$j . '_' . $i]))
            $distances[$i][$j] = @$_POST[$j . '_' . $i];
        else
            $distances[$i][$j] = 32767;
    }
}
```

I am getting an fatal error. The error say " Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression `(you can use "null !== expression" instead)` " 
But I don't know what's wrong in that code.. in old `xampp 1.7.3` I didn't saw that error.

Please guide me.

Comment: Remove `@` since it doesn't make any sense in that (or mostly any) context. Putting a `@` in front of the variable makes it into an expression. You want to check the variable.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just remove `isset` where you are using `$_POST`.
This will automatically check if the value is there else you have settled default value.

**Updated**

As per @magnus idea, remove `@` before `$_POST`.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= CITY_COUNT; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= CITY_COUNT; $j++) {
        if ($_POST[$i . '_' . $j] != '')
            //
            $distances[$i][$j] = $_POST[$i . '_' . $j];
        else if ($_POST[$j . '_' . $i] != '')
            $distances[$i][$j] = $_POST[$j . '_' . $i];
        else
            $distances[$i][$j] = 32767;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a _terrible_ idea. Instead of removing isset(), you should remove the `@` in front of the variable you want to check. Simply use the function as it's intended to be used: `isset($_POST[....])`

Comment: Without the `isset()` a wearning is thrown each time a non existing value is referenced. Not a good diea.

Comment: well .. it's works perfect, thanks a lot but i'm still not understand why after i update xampp version i have many error and i must be change the code manualy..like some code it's not working in tag with <?php but its work with <? tag.
anyway thanks for help see my mistake placed code

Comment: it's right i have problem with isset code, POST code, and GET code.
some code POST it's won't running right without @$_POST after i'm getting error from many code. but actually misplaced my code after i'm change my xampp version. 
it's show up when i'm running it.
before i'm update xampp i not get any error. like this code :
before code is
$format_mysql =  $_POST[tahun].'-'.$_POST[bulan].'-'.$_POST[tanggal];  
 now the code is must like this :

$format_mysql =  @$_POST[tahun].'-'.@$_POST[bulan].'-'.@$_POST[tanggal];

Comment: @dimasadhipradana, I suggest you to read comment above. Your may have fixed the issue temporary but again, removing isset() is a terrible idea. Secondly, you may have overwriiten your php.ini during your migration that was why error showed up. Example, short tag <? ?> was turn on in your old php.ini http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: @dimasadhipradana : Micheal is right. I have coded this as per your error. You have to check with `isset()` function though as I told because of your error, I have answered like this.